# jQuery : Detect when element is scrolled to

Tags: jquery, events, element

I'd like to detect when an element is scrolled to (made visible via scrolling) via jQuery. Is there a way to do it with the .live() function, so that every new element in the page would trigger the event when they are scrolled to ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Use the Waypoints plugin: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/ Some examples: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#examples

Comment: I didn't realize I dug this up...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible..

Try:

```
$(".whatever").live("hover",
    function()
    {
        // Your code here
    }
);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3dKje/1/

Sorry I dug this up..

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-on-scrolled-to

```
$('.my-div').onScrolledTo(0.5,
    function() {
        alert('you scrolled to .my-div element');
    }
);
```